# How can I show a Jfreechart into a javafx Pane on GUI application?

Tags: java, javafx, jfreechart

I am new to JavaFX, and I am having difficulties trying to show a JFreechart on a JavaFX StackPane. This StackPane is being referenced from an FXML file built on SceneBuilder. I successfully set my controller and I am identifying the StackPane with an @FXML reference in the controller. I tried using ChartCanvas and add it to this stackPane, but I was unable to make it work. I don't really know what other alternatives I have for this particular scenario.

Here is my main:

```
public class SolarSizerAppMain extends Application {

private Stage primaryStage;
private BorderPane rootLayout;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("PV Sizer App");

    initRootLayout();

    showSolarSizerOverview();
}

/**
 * Initializes the root Layout
 */
private void initRootLayout() {
    try {
        // load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(SolarSizerAppMain.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

        // show the scene containinf the root layout
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * show the solar sizer overview inside the root layout
 */
private void showSolarSizerOverview() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(SolarSizerAppMain.class.getResource("view/EnergyOverview.fxml"));
        AnchorPane sizerOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        // set the energy overview into the center of root layout.
        rootLayout.setCenter(sizerOverview);

        // give the controller access to the main app.
        EnergyOverviewController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setSolarSizerAppMain(this);
        controller.showChartPanel();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



/**
 * Returns the main stage
 * 
 * @return
 */
public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
    return primaryStage;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Here is my Controller class:

```
public class EnergyOverviewController {

@FXML
private TableView<Meter> meterTable;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Meter, String> meterNumberColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Meter, String> startDateColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Meter, String> endDateColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Meter, Boolean> activatedColumn;

@FXML
private Button addMeterButton, deleteMeterButton;

@FXML
private StackPane chartPane;

@FXML
private SplitPane mainSplitPane;

// reference to the main
private SolarSizerAppMain solarSizerAppMain;

// reference to the database
private Database database;

private TimeSeriesCollection consumptionCollection;

private TimeSeriesCollection temperatureCollection;

private XYItemRenderer consumptionRenderer;

/**
 * Contructorof the controller
 */
public EnergyOverviewController() {
    database = new Database();
}

/**
 * Initializes the controller class. This method is automatically called
 * after fxml file has been loaded.
 */
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    // first check if there are current meters
    if (database.getMeters() != null) {
        // initialize the meter table with all the columns.
        meterNumberColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getMeterNumber());
        startDateColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> Assistant.parsePropertiesString(cellData.getValue()
                .getStartDate().toString()));
        endDateColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> Assistant.parsePropertiesString(cellData.getValue()
                .getEndDate().toString()));
    } else {
        //TODO: Handle if there are no meters with a dialog
    }

}


/**
 * Handles the meter import once the btn has been clicked
 */
@FXML 
private void handleMeterImport(){
    //TODO: do the meter import
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

    //set the extension filter
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("TXT files (*.txt)", "*.txt");
    fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File("C:/Users/Uzquianoj1/Google Drive/Thesis/TMY3 Database"));
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);

    //show open file dialog
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(solarSizerAppMain.getPrimaryStage());
    showProgressDialog(file);
}

/**
 * Method to display the chart
 */
public void showChartPanel() {
    TimeSeriesCollection consumptionCollection = new TimeSeriesCollection();
    String chartTitle = "Interval Data";
    String xAxisLabel = "Date";
    String yAxisLabel = "Consumption kWh";

    consumptionRenderer = new XYAreaRenderer();
    JFreeChart timeSeriesChart = ChartComponentsFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
            chartTitle, xAxisLabel, yAxisLabel, consumptionCollection,
            consumptionRenderer, "15 minutes");
    ChartCanvas canvas = new ChartCanvas(timeSeriesChart);
    chartPane.getChildren().add(canvas);//not working
}

@FXML
private void handleDeleteMeter(){
    //TODO: Handle the deletion of a meter. 
}

public void setSolarSizerAppMain(SolarSizerAppMain mainApp){
    solarSizerAppMain = mainApp;

}
```

}

And this link is where my fxml is located [raw text fxml](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=yYjynnCB), where i am calling the pane I want to put the chart into as "chartPane".

Any guidance or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java8 you can use a [SwingNode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html) to host swing components such as a [ChartPanel](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html).  SwingNode is a JavaFX component that allows you to set a swing component that will be displayed in the JavaFX scene.

The respective threading rules for both Swing and JavaFX must still be respected. This means the ChartPanel must always be created and updated on the Swing EDT and the SwingNode must always be updated on the JavaFX application thread.  Depending on how your application is designed this can get quite complicated.

Comment: Thank you very much @Aaron, It make sense and I could solve it by running the swing node as a separate thread using SwingUtilities.
 
This actually does exactly what I wanted to do. Too bad I can't really make use of the Jfreechart.fx packages.